# how to redirect a form error to the form page with validaton errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-2.0

i had created a form with user details and written a class view to update users details in my django aapp, everything is working but, instead of form widgets i hand coded form in page through that form i am updating the details. I didn't understand how to redirect a form error from class view to form page with error, in django errors it's showing that **doesn't contain aapp/user_form.html template**.

### Html code in "profile.html" page which contain form

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="{% url 'updatedprofile' user.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="modalBox">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
              <h4>Update Profile</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 icon">
              <p><a href="{% url 'mprofile' %}"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{user.first_name}}" class="form-control no-border simplebox" placeholder="Enter Your First Name Here...">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}" class="form-control no-border simplebox" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name Here...">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Mobile: </td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="number" name="mobile" value="{{user.mobile}}" class="form-control no-border simplebox" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number Here..."></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Profile Pic: </td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="file" name="avatar" value="{{user.avatar}}" class="form-control no-border simplebox"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
            <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Services</button></center>
                </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

### view code

```
class UpdateMprofile(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutIfNotSuperuserMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('mlogin')
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'avatar']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mprofile')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you doesn't define the `template_name` in your view, so you are getting the template error. First fix this -

```
class UpdateMprofile(LoginRequiredMixin, LogoutIfNotSuperuserMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = aapp/profile.html #Template directory should be correct.
    login_url = reverse_lazy('mlogin')
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'avatar']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mprofile')
```

Django is already rending the errors but in your template you haven't coded it to show errors.

To show all errors at a time you could you -

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{error}}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you want to render error with their field, use this -

```
   {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
        <span class="help-block text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
```

One more recommendation, for forms use - `Widget Tweaks`, here is good [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html).

Comment: Dear pankaj sharma thanks for teaching me... ithought in class based views it would redirect automatically to succes_ url if any error's will rise but i got clarity now that only on successful approach success_url works

Answer (score 0):

As you are using generic view, you should follow the Django template naming. 
In your question, you are getting a template error, so you should add template with `_form` suffix, e.g. `yourmodelname_form.html`. Django will automatically search it in your template folder, [Refer Official Document Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Validation error can be shown in,

```
{{form.non_field_errors}}
```

Note: It is better to use forms.py to edit.